# Remove doctype containing entity from xml using java

Tags: java, regex, xml, string, regular-language

I'm trying to process an xml, before that i need to remove the doctype and entity declaration from the input xml.

I'm using the below code to remove the doctype and entity:

```
fileContent = fileContent.replaceAll("<!ENTITY ((.|\n|\r)*?)\">", "");
fileContent = fileContent.replaceAll("<!DOCTYPE((.|\n|\r)*?)>", "");
```

This removes the entity and then the doctype. 
This works fine if the xml contains below doctype declarations in the xml:

```
<!DOCTYPE ichicsr SYSTEM "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">

<!DOCTYPE ichicsr SYSTEM "D:\UPGRADE\NTServices\Server\\Xml21.dtd"
[<!ENTITY % entitydoc SYSTEM "D:\UPGRADE\NTServices\Server\\latin-entities.dtd"> %entitydoc;]>
```

But if I have the doctype as given below, it doesn't work and the root tag in the xml get stripped off:

```
<!DOCTYPE ichicsr SYSTEM "D:\UPGRADE\NTServices\Server\\Xml21.dtd" 
[<!ENTITY % entitydoc SYSTEM 'D:\UPGRADE\NTServices\Server\\Xml21.dtd'>
]>
```

Please let me know if the regular expression I'm using is incorrect or any other action needs to be taken.

Comment: Never use `(.|\n|\r)*?`, use `.*?` with `Pattern.DOTALL` (or inline `(?s)` variant), or at least `[\s\S]*?`.

Comment: Try a single replacement `replaceAll("<!DOCTYPE[^<>]*(?:<!ENTITY[^<>]*>[^<>]*)?>", "")`

Comment: Thanks Wiktor. 
It worked for me.
But, is there a way to handle upper case and lower case doctype and entity using a single pattern ?

Comment: Well, yours does not work because you have `"` required before `>` in ENTITIY   regex. You may just replace `\"` with `['\"]` there.

Comment: ok.. got it. 
 But, is there a way to handle upper case and lower case doctype and entity using a single pattern

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your approach does not work because you have `"` required before final `>` in the `ENTITIY` regex. You may just replace `\"` with `['\"]` there.

Besides, never use `(.|\n|\r)*?` in any regex since it is a performance killer. Instead, use `.*?` with `Pattern.DOTALL` (or inline `(?s)` variant), or at least `[\s\S]*?`.

However, there is a better way: merge the two regexps into one:

```
fileContent = fileContent.replaceAll("(?i)<!DOCTYPE[^<>]*(?:<!ENTITY[^<>]*>[^<>]*)?>", "");
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KBOJfu/1).

**Details**

- `(?i)` - case insensitive `Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE` inline modifier
- `<!DOCTYPE` - literal text
- `[^<>]*` - 0+ chars other than `<` and `>`
- `(?:<!ENTITY[^<>]*>[^<>]*)?` - an optional occurrence of

  - `<!ENTITY`
  - `[^<>]*` - 0+ chars other than `<` and `>`
  - `>` - a `>` char
  - `[^<>]*` - 0+ chars other than `<` and `>`
- `>` - a `>` char.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution wiktor.